# Magento2 - How to get estimate shipping rates for guest users using js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, shipping, webapi, guest

I have followd this [link](https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-get-estimate-shipping-in-magento2-using-js/) to get estimate shipping rates, its working fine for logged in user. But I need to implement this with guest user as well.

I have changed service url for guest user as explained in the article and pass static quote id for testing purpose.

> serviceUrl =
>   'rest/default/V1/guest-carts/:quoteId/estimate-shipping-methods'

Service with quote id :

> serviceUrl =
>   'rest/default/V1/guest-carts/317/estimate-shipping-methods'

But its throwing error.

[image]

Can anyone help.. how we can achieve it for guest user?

Comment: Tried using `/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods` ?

Comment: Rhys, thanks for the comment. Yes, I tried. It only works for logged in user.

Comment: The only dynamic variable you need here is quote-id, have a look at FILE: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js, function: getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsForNewAddress